# Table Column width won't change

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table 900px wide with 13 columns. The problem I'm having is that my first column `Tap` won't change regardless of the width I give it. I want to make the first column smaller so that my last column doesn't look as squished.

This is what my table looks like:
[image]

I've even tried adding a `style="width: 40px;"` to my first column but it doesn't affect it.

```css
.print_ttr {
  width: 900px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.print_ttr th {
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.print_ttr td {
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.print_tableInputBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.holder{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.section{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="holder">
  <table class="print_ttr">
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th style="width: 30px;">Tap</th>
     <th>Primary Voltage</th>
     <th>Secondary Voltage</th>
     <th>Calculated Ratio</th>
     <th>Phase A Ratio</th>
     <th>Phase A Excitation[mA]</th>
     <th>Phase A Deviation %</th>
     <th>Phase B Ratio</th>
     <th>Phase B Excitation[mA]</th>
     <th>Phase B Deviation %</th>
     <th>Phase C Ratio</th>
     <th>Phase C Excitation[mA]</th>
     <th>Phase C Deviation %</th>
   </tr>


   <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_334_7556" value="1">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_334_7556" value="28980">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_334_7556" value="600">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_334_7556" value="48.3000">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_334_7556" value="48.1370">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_334_7556" value="1.542">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_334_7556" value="0.338">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_334_7556" value="48.1380">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_334_7556" value="2.493">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_334_7556" value="0.338">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_334_7556" value="48.3220">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_334_7556" value="2.398">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_334_7556" value="0.045">
     </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_335_7556" value="2">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_335_7556" value="28290">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_335_7556" value="600">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_335_7556" value="47.1500">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_335_7556" value="47.2070">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_335_7556" value="1.598">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_335_7556" value="0.120">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_335_7556" value="47.2110">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_335_7556" value="2.594">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_335_7556" value="0.122">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_335_7556" value="47.2250">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_335_7556" value="2.525">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_335_7556" value="0.159">
     </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_336_7556" value="3">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_336_7556" value="27600">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_336_7556" value="600">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_336_7556" value="46.0000">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_336_7556" value="46.0070">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_336_7556" value="1.689">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_336_7556" value="0.010">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_336_7556" value="46.0070">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_336_7556" value="2.704">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_336_7556" value="0.010">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_336_7556" value="46.0160">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_336_7556" value="2.601">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_336_7556" value="0.010">
     </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_337_7556" value="4">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_337_7556" value="26910">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_337_7556" value="600">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_337_7556" value="44.8500">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_337_7556" value="44.9060">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_337_7556" value="1.773">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_337_7556" value="0.124">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_337_7556" value="44.9080">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_337_7556" value="2.830">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_337_7556" value="0.124">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_337_7556" value="44.9160">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_337_7556" value="2.736">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_337_7556" value="0.147">
     </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_338_7556" value="5">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_338_7556" value="26220">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_338_7556" value="600">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_338_7556" value="43.7000">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_338_7556" value="43.7160">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_338_7556" value="1.857">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_338_7556" value="0.036">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_338_7556" value="43.7090">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_338_7556" value="2.970">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_338_7556" value="0.020">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_338_7556" value="43.7130">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_338_7556" value="2.874">
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_338_7556" value="0.029">
     </td>
   </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML for the table would be helpful as well.  Especially since it's a table.

Comment: Tables are a pain, unless you really know how to use them. Widths on columns usually work best with percentages, because of the way tables are calculated.

Comment: The `Tap` column is already small. Look [here](http://jsbin.com/haziwu/1/)

Comment: did you change any of the css @KingShimkus? the picture is what my table ends up looking like, the tap is super wide

Comment: No I did not change any of the CSS. I just simply copied and pasted the code into JS Bin.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting your code into JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/haziwu/1/edit?output), this is what it came out as:

[image: Table Column]

Even after adding your container div:

[image: Proof!]

You can try adding this to your code:

```
.print_ttr th:first-child{
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 30px;
}
```

I don't know what is going on, but I am pretty sure this is what you were looking for. I am using Google Chrome. Even after inserting your code into a code snippet it still comes out that way. Look here:

```css
.print_ttr {
  width: 900px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.print_ttr th {
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.print_ttr td {
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.print_tableInputBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="print_ttr">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 30px;">Tap</th>
      <th>Primary Voltage</th>
      <th>Secondary Voltage</th>
      <th>Calculated Ratio</th>
      <th>Phase A Ratio</th>
      <th>Phase A Excitation[mA]</th>
      <th>Phase A Deviation %</th>
      <th>Phase B Ratio</th>
      <th>Phase B Excitation[mA]</th>
      <th>Phase B Deviation %</th>
      <th>Phase C Ratio</th>
      <th>Phase C Excitation[mA]</th>
      <th>Phase C Deviation %</th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_334_7556" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_334_7556" value="28980">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_334_7556" value="600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_334_7556" value="48.3000">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_334_7556" value="48.1370">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_334_7556" value="1.542">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_334_7556" value="0.338">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_334_7556" value="48.1380">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_334_7556" value="2.493">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_334_7556" value="0.338">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_334_7556" value="48.3220">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_334_7556" value="2.398">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_334_7556" value="0.045">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_335_7556" value="2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_335_7556" value="28290">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_335_7556" value="600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_335_7556" value="47.1500">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_335_7556" value="47.2070">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_335_7556" value="1.598">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_335_7556" value="0.120">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_335_7556" value="47.2110">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_335_7556" value="2.594">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_335_7556" value="0.122">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_335_7556" value="47.2250">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_335_7556" value="2.525">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_335_7556" value="0.159">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_336_7556" value="3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_336_7556" value="27600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_336_7556" value="600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_336_7556" value="46.0000">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_336_7556" value="46.0070">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_336_7556" value="1.689">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_336_7556" value="0.010">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_336_7556" value="46.0070">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_336_7556" value="2.704">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_336_7556" value="0.010">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_336_7556" value="46.0160">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_336_7556" value="2.601">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_336_7556" value="0.010">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_337_7556" value="4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_337_7556" value="26910">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_337_7556" value="600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_337_7556" value="44.8500">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_337_7556" value="44.9060">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_337_7556" value="1.773">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_337_7556" value="0.124">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_337_7556" value="44.9080">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_337_7556" value="2.830">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_337_7556" value="0.124">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_337_7556" value="44.9160">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_337_7556" value="2.736">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_337_7556" value="0.147">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_0_338_7556" value="5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_1_338_7556" value="26220">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_2_338_7556" value="600">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_3_338_7556" value="43.7000">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_4_338_7556" value="43.7160">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_5_338_7556" value="1.857">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_6_338_7556" value="0.036">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_7_338_7556" value="43.7090">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_8_338_7556" value="2.970">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_9_338_7556" value="0.020">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_10_338_7556" value="43.7130">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_11_338_7556" value="2.874">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="print_tableInputBox" name="ttr_12_338_7556" value="0.029">
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ill add my container div  incase that may be it. My table is wrapped in a container

Comment: well I am completely stumped then

Comment: tried to add that but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'll have to dig to see if i can find the problem.